# math.net numerics columnsum taking long time

Tags: c#, math.net

What are the best practices to follow for `math.net numerics` matrices/vectors calculations in `asp.net/c#`.

I'm performing huge number of (10000*30*35) matrices calculations. I'm using `Intel MKL provider` and `C#.Net TPL` but still it's taking ~40 seconds on 16 core system which is not acceptable,trying to bring it under 3-4 seconds.

All are dense matrices. When  I checked with dotTrace profiler tool, columnsum is taking more time.

Any thoughts??

Below is sample code:

```
Parallel.For(0, count, (i) =>
                {

                for (int j = 0; j < year; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < iterations; k++)
                    {
                        a.PointwiseMultiply(b); 
                        a.Multiply(b); a.Multiply(b);
                        a.Add(b);
                        a.Add(b).Subtract(b);
                        a.ColumnSums(); a.ColumnSums();
                        a.Subtract(1);
                        a.Multiply(2);

                    }
                }
                 //Interlocked.Decrement(ref tc);
                                });
```

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? What iss A? What is B? 
If they're variables outside the scope, then parallelization is of no use here.

Comment: @Emiswelt This is just sample code. Each iteration (i) is independent so using Parallel.For loop